# Can’t get the data from nested components within dynamic zones

Tags: graphql, strapi

Related to Strapi forum -> https://forum.strapi.io/t/resolved-cant-get-the-data-from-nested-components-within-dynamic-zones/15896/3

Is there any elastic way to request dynamic zones via Graphql without explicitly defining each of them in a query?
For example, I DON’T want to do something like this:

```
query Homepage {
  components {
    ... on SliderComponent {
      image
      text
    }
    ... on ParagraphComponent {
      title
      description
    }
    // and so on...
  }
}
```

Instead, somehow, I’d like to be able to get all of the dynamic zones without querying them separately.
So ideally would be something like this:

```
query Homepage {
  components
}
```

and that would return all of the possible dynamic zone components with their nested fields.

The best scenario is to query all the nested data within the dynamic zones using something like in RestApi http://localhost:1337/api/pages?populate[dynamiczones]

**NOTE: I know that the queries above are not correct, but this is just an idea of the query shape.**